# Is there any book covering solutions to matrix equations that are more complicated than $AX+C=B$? (eg, $AX+XB=I$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, book-recommendation

I like Linear Algebra.But most Matrix Equation problems stop like $AX+C=B$ where you have to solve for $X$. Sometimes I see complicated ones like $AX+XB=I$. I was wondering if there's a book where they deal with this complicated problems or has problems like these.

Comment: You see the book: Gantmacher F. R.,  The Theory of Matrices, chapter VIII

Comment: $AX+XB=C$ is a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation).

Comment: Gantmacher's book can be downloaded [here](https://archive.org/details/theoryofmatrices00gant/page/n3/mode/2up)

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll look into Gantmacher's book